# Define 1-to-1 AND 1-to-many relationship on same object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Been looking at this for a while now...about brain dead.

I have a parent object (OwnerGroup) and a child object (Owner).  This relationship is 1-to-many.  In addition, OwnerGroup has a primary Owner so we have two properties: int PrimaryOwnerId and Owner PrimaryOwner.  I need to define a 1-to-1 relationship between this and Owner.  Below are the POCOs:

```
public class OwnerGroup
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int PrimaryOwnerId { get; set; }
   public Owner PrimaryOwner { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
}

public class Owner
{
   public int OwnerGroupId { get; set; }
   ...

   public virtual OwnerGroup{ get; set; }
}
```

Defining the FK from OwnerGroup to Owner is easy, see below:

```
builder.Entity<Owner>()
                .HasRequired<OwnerGroup >(x => x.OwnerGroup )
                .WithMany(x => x.Owners)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.OwnerGroupId);
```

The part that is tripping me up is defining the PrimaryOwner FK to Owner.  I guess, technically, this field (PrimaryOwnerId) should be nullable?

As always, any help is appreciated.

Comment: can an owner be a primary owner of multiple owner groups ?

Comment: Does an `OnwerGroup` require a `PrimaryOwner`?

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi yes, an owner could possibly be the primary owner for multiple groups.

Comment: @jjj ideally yes, a group should always have a primary owner.